# Nuxt.js npm run build results in some JS files being not found

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js, code-splitting

I have a Nuxt.js `^2.10.2` App.

When I do `npm run dev`, the project builds perfectly.

When I do `npm run build` then `npm run start`. some JS files are getting 404 error.

[image]

```
ERROR

Request URL: http://localhost:3000/_nuxt/vendors.pages/account.pages/ca.pages/cart.pages/category/_id/
index.pages/checkout/_step/index.pages/.f705ad4d.1-0-128.js
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:3000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

The file exists on my project in `dist/_nuxt/vendor.pages/......` with the correct filename `.f705ad4d.1-0-128.js`

my `nuxt.config.js`

```
build: {,
    filenames: {
        app: '[name].' + version + '.js',
        chunk: '[name].' + version + '.js',
        vendor: '[name].' + version + '.js',
        manifest: '[name].' + version + '.js',
    },
}
```

What am I doing wrong? As other files are loaded as normal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the answer. Files starting with `.` dont work. not sure how to fix it though

**Temoporary Fix:**

in my `nuxt.config.js` I added

```js
build: {
 filenames: {
    app: ({ isDev }) => isDev ? '[name].js' : '[chunkhash].js',
    chunk: ({ isDev }) => isDev ? '[name].js' : '[chunkhash].js',
    css: ({ isDev }) => isDev ? '[name].css' : '[contenthash].css',
    img: ({ isDev }) => isDev ? '[path][name].[ext]' : 'img/[hash:7].[ext]',
    font: ({ isDev }) => isDev ? '[path][name].[ext]' : 'fonts/[hash:7].[ext]',
    video: ({ isDev }) => isDev ? '[path][name].[ext]' : 'videos/[hash:7].[ext]'
  }
}
```

REFERECE:
https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/#filenames

or just this would work too

```js
build: {
  filenames: {
    chunk: ({ isDev }) => isDev ? '[name].js' : '[chunkhash].js'
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it have to start with a . ? Can you browse out to the path?

Comment: basically if I change the file name it works. Not sure why this file has no name though. need to investigate.

Comment: I had issues with the `npm run dev`, but the production build was fine. After setting up chunk names, everything works.

Comment: @Garine you just saved us days worth of headbanging. Thanks a lot man.