# Unable to understand chrome dev tools memory tab

Tags: nuxt.js, google-chrome-devtools

Firstly If someone has better title, let me know will update.

Now main point : I want to understand where detached nodes are originating from using Chrome devtools memory tab.

Please see the attached picture.
In this, I have multiple detached nodes.
But when I click on any example-button, it opens another tree in Object section.
On expanding tree in Object, another tree opens. So it is very difficult to understand what exactly to look for.

Also the app is nuxt app, so file names are also random_alpha_numeric.js like 654ere4.js

[image]

So in the image above, how to know what is referring selected detached button node.
Any help would be truly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: You could set the actual names of the files rather than the hashes as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59293485/8816585). I don't have much experience with this tab and I'm not sure of what you're looking for here exactly. It may be a bit complex to debug from here directly, maybe the performance tab of the Vue devtools can help you find some performance bottlenecks with some specific rendering times, then you could inspect those in this tab yeah.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into this & share if I found anything solid.